# Space separated IDS treated differently in a text file

Tags: count, line, uniq

Input file looks something like this:

```
123 456
456 869
123 562
562 123
```

How do I find the total amount of IDs?

What i've tried so far:

```
cat file | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c
```

Which gives:

```
2 123
1 123
1 456
1 456
1 562
1 562
1 869
```

Which would give a total of 7 uniq IDs, but there are 4: 123, 456, 562 and 869

Comment: My first guess is that the file has DOS line terminators. What does `file file` return? (the first `file` is a command, the second is your input file) You can also try `sed 's/\r//' file | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c`.

Comment: That works! file file returns - ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators. Which means it uses line breaks as \r\n right?

Comment: That's correct. `123` is a different string than `123\r`.